# Instantiate MEF parts in a separate process

Tags: .net, mef, maf

Is it possible  in MEF  to instantiate each plugin as a separate process?  Or should i have to use MAF?

*PS: I see an interesting article  at http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2011/07/isolating-mef-components.html

[ i can not able to run application, it crash]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MEF doesn't support that out of the box. But you could write your own ExportProvider which tries to handle this, and pass it to the CompositionContainer constructor.